# using openlayers 3 and three.js to use openlayers 3 map as texture

Tags: openstreetmap, terrain, 3d-map, three-js

I am trying to use Openlayers 3 along with three.js to use openlayers output map as texture. I found that openlayers 3 is webgl based and so is three.js. So they must be compatible.

What I have done is displayed a map using ol.js function ol.Map().Now i want the map to be used as a texture in a terrain.

I think if i get the map as an image file instead of displaying in div container. The problem would be solved. But am unable to do it.

I have a terrain and a map but unable to use the map as texture for the terrain.

Can anybody help me with this. I am stuck and with no idea of what to do?
I have asked this in stackoverflow also.

Comment: Have a look at this article - https://javascript.plainenglish.io/openlayers-and-three-js-99c904eed76c It perfectly describes what you're looking for.